# Deploy multiple lambda functions using terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

*Don't mark this as duplicate due to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706578/deploy-at-once-multiple-aws-netcore-lambda-functions)*

I have a "aws_lambda_function" resource and it works fine.

Now I want to deploy another lambda function, I tried copying the entire block with a different handler and alias but it throws an error. Is there any other way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Here is the terraform code:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "api_service" {
  function_name = "${substr("${local.api_artifact_name}", 0, min(64, length(local.api_artifact_name)))}"

  # Artifacts bucket
  s3_bucket = "${local.artifacts_bucket_name}"
  s3_key    = "${module.artifact-upload.artifact_key}"

  # "index" is the filename within the zip file (main.js) and "handler"
  # is the name of the property under which the handler function was
  # exported in that file.
  handler = "index.api"

  runtime = "nodejs8.10"
  role    = "${module.api-service-iam.iam_role_arn}"

  # Optional, but ensures that things don't constantly refresh during local development
  source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("${local.api_dist_dir}"))}"

  environment {
    variables  =  {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Now the resource `api_service` deploys one Lambda function successfully but how can I go about to deploy, say, 5 such functions?

*`All these Lambda functions will be invoked by an API Gateway later.`*

Comment: What does your Terraform code look like and what is the exact error you get when you run either `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`?

Comment: That is a good question, I will update my post.

Comment: that's a good question and I am trying to figure this out too. I have 20 something Lambda functions to deploy. The only way i could think of is using vars as `type=map` and then list every individual Lambda function config in the map then use `count=??` in the `tf` script and `${count.index}` to loop through the map. Haven't tried it though, I am still working on it.

Comment: @Geet Choubey did you found a way to do it?

Comment: @dege yes it worked.

Comment: @GeetChoubey after i made the comment i also found way to do it a bit inspired by Annjawn, if you i can post what i did

Answer (score 2):

So basically the answer was staring right at my face the whole time.

I copied the entire resource block and made the following changes:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda-1" {
  function_name = "lambda-1-${substr("${local.api_artifact_name}", 0, min(64, length(local.api_artifact_name)))}"

  # Artifacts bucket
  s3_bucket = "${local.artifacts_bucket_name}"
  s3_key    = "${module.artifact-upload.artifact_key}"

  # "index" is the filename within the zip file (main.js) and "handler"
  # is the name of the property under which the handler function was
  # exported in that file.
  handler = "lambda-1/index.api"

  runtime = "nodejs8.10"
  role    = "${module.api-service-iam.iam_role_arn}"

  # Optional, but ensures that things don't constantly refresh during local development
  source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("${local.api_dist_dir}"))}"

}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda-2" {
  function_name = "lambda-2-${substr("${local.api_artifact_name}", 0, min(64, length(local.api_artifact_name)))}"

  # Artifacts bucket
  s3_bucket = "${local.artifacts_bucket_name}"
  s3_key    = "${module.artifact-upload.artifact_key}"

  # "index" is the filename within the zip file (main.js) and "handler"
  # is the name of the property under which the handler function was
  # exported in that file.
  handler = "lambda-2/index.api"

  runtime = "nodejs8.10"
  role    = "${module.api-service-iam.iam_role_arn}"

  # Optional, but ensures that things don't constantly refresh during local development
  source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("${local.api_dist_dir}"))}"

}
```

> Make sure they have different **function names**

Answer (score 1):

I basically create one directory per lambda, with  a naming convention for artifacts like policy.json, ssm_parameters.json.

1) I use an external data source to get a list lambda functions in the directory, and get all the meta-data necessary for each Lambda
2) I use count="N" to deploy each lambda resource.

Comment: This was the second approach that I was going to follow but since the number of lambdas are less, I am able to deploy it using multiple blocks only. Thanks though.